# Why the event on stream is not fired with peerjs and with cordova-plugin-iosrtc when i receive a call?

Tags: ionic-framework, webrtc, peerjs

i 'm working with peerjs and iosrtc plugin and i have got a problem on reception with ios, this method is never fired.

```
call.on('stream', (stream) => {
document.getElementById('camera').srcObject = stream;
});
```

And this event neither:

```
call.peerConnection.addEventListener('addstream', (e: any) => {
document.getElementById('camera').srcObject = e.stream;
});
```

And to finish as i've read on other post, this method doesn't exist anymore today

```
call.peerConnection.onaddstream = function (stream) { // do something with stream }.
```

Someone find the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot of testing to try and figure out the problem with various recommendations and help.
I created a project from scratch to reproduce the problem.
But when I finished, the POC, the project is running and I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Finally after looking everywhere, I noticed that the plugin version was different.
my poc used 6.0.20 and my project 6.0.18.
So I changed the version and now the event is triggered when I get a call.

For information, I share the POC if it can help anyone.
https://github.com/iometrine/ionic-iosrtc-peerjs